# AngularJS ng-class, condition when form is dirty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my main html (lets say it uses ng-controller="controller1"), I'd like to put a conditional class on a div that would change its background color whenever a form under ng-controller="controller2" is dirty.

Is there a way to just put that as a conditional statement inside a ng-class?

There will be multiple forms and multiple correlating divs that need to coordinate, so I was just trying to come up with the simplest way possible.

EDIT- Example Code of my current setup:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="testapp">
<body ng-controller="ControllerA">
    <p ng-class="{'updates-made' : boolUpdatesMade}">
        My background will change whenever an update is made on the form
    </p>

    <form name="editForm" ng-controller="ControllerB">
        <input type="text" name="changeme">
        <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller.js:

```
testapp.controller("ControllerB", function($scope){
    $scope.save = function(){
        if($scope.editForm.$dirty){
            $scope.boolUpdatesMade = true;
        }

    }
}
```

What I'd expect to happen is that when I set boolUpdatesMade=true in ControllerB, the CSS class "updates-made" would be applied to the

in the HTML.  This isn't the case.

Here's a link to the JSFiddle for this example: http://jsfiddle.net/tPGLT/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Parent Controller cannot tell when a model inside the Child Controller changes without using $watch.

(In this case, the model being watched is not too big. However, its worthy to note what the doc reads: 
"*To save the value of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used. 
It also means that watching complex options will have adverse memory and performance implications.*")

There is an easier way to do what you want without using $watch:

```
testapp.controller("ControllerA", function($scope){     
    $scope.boolUpdatesMade = false;

    $scope.updateForm = function(){
        $scope.boolUpdatesMade = true;
    }
}

testapp.controller("ControllerB", function($scope){
    $scope.save = function(){       
        if($scope.editForm.$dirty){
            // dont update the parent's model inside the child
            // instead have the parent's method do that
            $scope.updateForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this led to me realizing that my one controller was actually a child of the other, not two totally independent controllers.  Though I now know about watch, all I simply had to do was $scope.$parent.boolUpdatesMade = true; and  ng-class="{'updates-made' : boolUpdatesMade}"

Comment: The above worked up until I created an app, and created the controllers using app.controller = , instead of function controller.  I'm back to figuring out how to properly watch the model. Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: can you put up a little code on fiddle demonstrating what you are trying to do?

Comment: I edited my original question to reflect what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I still can't get it to work properly. I created a fiddle here in order to have something real-world to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/tPGLT/1/

Comment: Got it, thanks for taking the time to help straighten me out!

Answer (score 3):

Angular already adds in a class called "ng-dirty" to a form (and the individual field) whenever it has been touched...assuming you have a form element to attach it to. Simplest is to create a CSS class with whatever styling you want based on that. If you preferred your own class, you could do an ng-class to evaluate the form state as such:

```
<form name="my_form" ng-class="{'class-name' : my_form.$dirty}">
```

EDIT:

Just saw that you want this on a different div. Assuming the Div is under the same controller as the form, this will still work:

```
<form name="my_form">
```

and

```
<div ng-class="{'class-name' : my_form.$dirty}">
```

If the div is under a different controller scope than the form, it's still possible, but you'll have to use events or a service to communicate between the two controllers.

Coffee kicking in now. Seeing that you *do* want to communicate between the controllers, you can use the $watch technique in the other answer to see that a model has changed (because a $watch won't work on a form state) and then use a service or $broadcast/$emit to set a var in the other controller.